# Angular filter contents of Directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to filter the contents of my custom custom element's ng-repeat by the `"cat":` property in my data JSON. I have basic experience with Angular directives but as you can tell my understanding is far from proficient. I have a feeling the issue lies in my directive with the scope{} and cat properties but I'm a little stuck as to how to proceed. Currently my HTML stands like so:

HTML:

```
<x-filtered-repeat cat="characters | filter : {cat: 'jedi'} : true | filter:query |orderBy: orderList"></x-filtered-repeat>
```

Template filtered-repeat.html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="character in characters">
        <h2>{{character.name}}</h2>
      </li>
    </ul>
    ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
.directive('filteredRepeat', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      cat: '='
},
    templateUrl: 'partials/filtered-repeat.html'
  };
});
```

JSON from JS file:

```
$scope.businesses = [
    {"name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
     "index":88,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Yoda",
     "index":69,
      "cat":"jedi"},
    {"name": "Lando",
     "index":31,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Han Solo",
     "index":90,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Darth Vader",
     "index":98,
      "cat": "sith"},
    {"name": "Jar-Jar Binks",
     "index":80,
      "cat": "alien"},
    {"name": "Mace Windu",
     "index":45,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Chewy",
     "index":76,
      "cat": "smuggler"}
  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your directive template try using the filtered array :

```
   <li data-ng-repeat="character in cat">
        <h2>{{character.name}}</h2>
   </li>
```